# Android keyboard "Go" button to "Search"

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

can any one tell how to get "Search" in place of "Go" or "Done" button in android keyboard. (not magnifying glass ) .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try
`myEditText.setImeActionLabel("Search",EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED)`.  `IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED` allows you to put whatever text you want in the button.

Comment: Still im getting magnifying glass ..  plz help me

Comment: try using EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED as the action

Comment: add android:inputType="text" also

Answer (score 19):

something like this

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```

might work. in your case

there are also other options like

```
android:imeActionLabel="Search"
```

**EDIT**

please check this thread as well. [LINK](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/0c1a939da59264d3)

accroding to the above link you get full text only in landscape mode.

> full label is only displayed when the IME has a large amount of space for it 
>   (such as when the standard keyboard is in fullscreen mode).

so i guess you can use `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"` and the text `Search` will appear in landscape only.

Comment: Hi sam, Still im getting magnifying glass for the above .. plz suggest me where im going wrong

Comment: did you use **android:imeActionLabel="Search"**

Comment: can you tell me what you see in landscape mode. and i have added an new link in the update.

Comment: yes  , this is what im using.`code` <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:hint="Search by keyword" 
    android:id="@+id/search_keyword"
       android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeActionLabel="Search"
       android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
       android:layout_weight="1"
   ></EditText> `code`

Comment: please check the link which i have added

Comment: remove **android:imeActionLabel="Search"** and keep **android:imeOptions="actionSearch"**. by the way what is you android version.

Comment: Sorry sam, in landscape mode im getting one "search button" on top right. but not one portrait. but still im getting magnifier glass in keypad.

Comment: check this [**LINK**](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/0c1a939da59264d3). according to this in portrait mode you only get mag..glass.

Comment: Thank u sam ! your link helped me lot .

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:singleLine="true" >
 </EditText>
```

Add "android:singleLine" to work properly

Answer (score 1):

Add below two line in your **EditText** tag :

```
 android:inputType="text"
 android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```

And Add the **setOnEditorActionListener()** method to editText as below:

```
  etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH){
                     doSearch(); //Do whatever you intend to do when user click on search button in keyboard.
                   }

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```