# android - imeOptions have search button say "Search" instead of magnifying glass

Tags: android, keyboard

I was wondering if its possible to change magnifying glass on the Search button to text "Search". We want to preserve the imeOptions setting to android:imeOptions="actionSearch" because we respond to a certain event.

Here is what I have:

```
<EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtSearch" 
        android:textSize="14px" 
        android:textColor="@color/main_text_black" 
        android:layout_width="189px" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@null" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="24px"/>
```

[image]

Tried this:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtSearch" 
    android:textSize="18dp" 
    android:textColor="@color/main_text_black" 
    android:layout_width="247dp" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
    android:imeActionLabel="Search"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@null" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"/>
```

[image]

This only works in landscape mode which our app does not support and the word Search shows up in the wrong place.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156427/android-keyboard-go-button-to-search/7156494#7156494

Comment: Did not work in the portret view, also in landscape mode it still has magnifying glass and Search word is overridden at the top but not where I need it to be.

Comment: did you change android:imeActionLabel="Search" with the unspecified attribute in your xml or did you do it at run time using java?

Answer (score 4):

You can try it!

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_search_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible unless you implement your own Keyboard for that EditText. The Text (or icons) on the keys of a keyboard is controlled by the person who wrote the keyboard.